# how to implement pagination using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

i am using `retrofit` to fetch data from server. As data is in a large chunk so we are fetching it using pagination.

but i dont know how could i line up pagination request in retrofit.

```
RestApi.DealersDataApi service = getDealersDataApi();
        Call<Dealers> call = service.getDealersData(userRequest);


        call.enqueue(new Callback<Dealers>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit2.Response<Dealers> response) {


                Dealers dealers = response.body();
                if(dealers!=null) {

                        String count = dealers.getCount();
                        int totalReq = getTotalPages(count);
                        // here totalReq is nothing but the total no.of request to fetch all dealer data


                    }
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

here count is total records of dealers and NO_OF_REC_PER_REQUEST is 100 that pulls 100 records in one request.

```
 private int getTotalPages(String count){

        double cnt = Double.valueOf(count);
        int totalReq  =(int) Math.ceil(cnt / NO_OF_REC_PER_REQUEST);
        return totalReq;
   }
```

UserRequest as a parameter that has count and pagenumber parameter as POST

```
serRequest userLoginRequest  = new UserRequest();
        userLoginRequest.setUserId("1234");
        userLoginRequest.setOrganizationId("ABCD");
        userLoginRequest.setCount("100"); // 100 per request 
        userLoginRequest.setPagenumber("0"); // start from
```

Comment: it depend on API u r using. you need the support from back-end guys to do this feature, you can not do it by yourself by only in client side.

Comment: backend is already done , i just need to pass the rquest

Comment: could you show the template of API and how did you implement?

Comment: seems that it's nice implementation. Did you try with another tool? Postman or some thing like that